# Issue with 'Will_paginate' while refresing the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using pagination for my review slide panel. The problem is that each time I click on 'next page' the page refresh and I have to go back to see that page.

Anyone knows the solution in this or similar situations?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give more information, put code example of what you are doing. and page refresh? and gives you what, a blank page? give us more details about the issue please